# How to make a small window like in google search

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me how we can make a small window like shown in google search home page(ad of chrome).Which will load when websites loads, it should be movable ,able to close it  and also place it in a specific location of webpage

[image]

Comment: There are approximately a million JavaScript dialog/pop-up libraries; just pick one.

Comment: Have you looked at some of the frameworks to implement this. JQuery has a nice implementation http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: @SandeepGB thanks i have gone through the site. i downloaded the dialog files but the dialog box is fixed in the downloaded file..how can i make it movable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can do this easily

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none; ">
    <p>A basic dialog window</p>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width:'300',
        height:'100',
        resizable:false,
        position:[140,300] // x and y   
    });
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9CzF/) and [**Custom Style**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9CzF/1/).

**Reference:** [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: can you tell me how to make it movable?

Comment: `$("#dialog").dialog({draggable: true})`, see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/m9CzF/), by default it's dragable.

Comment: Also check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m9CzF/1/).

Comment: Move it by dragging the `titlebar`.